# MaxCDN Pre-Caching Script

Tags: caching, cdn

I am using Maxcdn and apparently my website files are not automatically cached on all Maxcdns servers worldwide unless there is a visitor first. Obviously, this can cause inconvenience and time delays for first visitors to my site as well it might have an impact on google rankings due to presumably slow loading times.

Is there a script which allows me to pre-cache files by simulating visitors from different world locations? MaxCDN has about 12 servers worldwide and therefore I need to simulate users from a close proximity to these locations.

Comment: Hey Joanna, Justin from MaxCDN here, I will see if we can get this into the road map.  It would be a great feature.  Send me an email if you have any other request: jdorfman at maxcdn.com

Comment: Have you considered writing a website monitoring script and then running the script from many locations around the globe?  This could easily be done using any of the available monitoring platforms like Neustar WPM and others.